# ggplot boxplot labels not showing

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, axis-labels

I am creating a boxplot and can get the plot to show, but the x and y axis ticks and labels do not show up. This occurs with my own data as well as with example data. Here is the example data (from http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Axes_(ggplot2)/:

```
bp <- ggplot(PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight)) +
  geom_boxplot()
bp
```

And the resulting figure

[image: figure from example data]

Setting the discrete x axis doesn't change anything either

```
bp + scale_x_discrete(limits=c("trt1","trt2","ctrl"))
```

results in changing the order of the boxplots but no labels show. Why aren't the ticks and labels showing up and how do I get them to show?

Comment: Re start `R` it looks like a conflict with other package. I ran your code and works fine!

Comment: Same thing, I run your code without problem.

Comment: After restarting, I got the same figure with no x axis ticks or labels. At one point on a different figure I turned off x axis ticks, could that be the issue? If so, is there a way to turn on x axis ticks and labels?

Comment: Run a clean R installation and just the `ggplot2` library.  This type of question has been posted before and it is very likely you have either another package causing some issues overlapping with `ggplot2` or you will need to update `ggplot2` and some of the required libraries.  Sometimes installing other packages overwrites packages used in `ggplot2` with incompatible versions.  If you update `ggplot2` and load just that package, it should be okay for you.

Comment: It looks like the package `ggtern` was the issue here. After uninstalling and reinstalling all packages but that one, it worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question was solved in the comments by @chemdork123 but wanted to post the answer here to close the question. I uninstalled all of the packages but the base and recommended packages, following the instructions found here https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-remove-all-user-installed-packages-in-r/. After uninstalling all packages, I reinstalled `ggplot2` and the captions appeared. After reinstalling each previous problem one by one I learned `ggtern` was the issue here. Removing `ggtern` and reinstalling `ggplot2` again fixed the issue and code runs perfectly.